# Python Lottery System only 6 numbers. I need help as each loop just adds onto the list. Help please

Tags: python

Python help here. Running this program results in list adding up everything, which I don't want as I only need 6 number lottery.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pydbg.png

Comment: Why do it manually when there is [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)? `lottery_list = random.sample(list(range(1, 54)), 6)` is all you need. And next time please give us your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this function

```py
def repeat():
    lotteryList = []
    for i in range(0, 6):
        while True:
            number = random.randint(1, 53)
            if number not in lotteryList:
                lotteryList.append(number)
                break
    print("These are your lottery numbers:", lotteryList)
```

I think the problem is that you defined your lotteryList outside the function meaning that it is a global variable and each call to repeat function will modify he same list